# Firestore onUpdate function not triggering

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

#### The problem

I'm using Firebase cloud functions with the emulator, and for some reason, the `onUpdate` trigger is not triggering, yet the `onCreate` function does trigger.

All code is TypeScript, and it's transpiled to JS to work on cloud functions.

```
// functions/src/music.ts

// this function runs
export const onMusicCreated = functions.firestore
    .document('music/{musicId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
        console.log('on create is running')
    })

// this function doesn't run
export const onMusicUpdated = functions.firestore
    .document('music/{musicId}')
    .onUpdate(async (change) => {
        console.log('on update is running')
    })
```

Both functions are async because in the final code,

On the front-end, when I run the `add` function on the front-end, the `onCreate` function fires.

```
const { id } = await firebase.firestore().collection('music').add({ title: 'hello world' })
```

The console log runs as expected and the emulator outputs this into the console:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "onMusicCreated"
i  functions: Finished "onMusicCreated" in ~1s
```

Yet when I update that same document, the `onUpdate` function doesn't run.

```
// "id" is the same id as above
await firebase.firestore().doc(`music/${id}`).update({ title: 'new title' })
```

Nothing happens. I can confirm that the document is actually updated when I look in the firestore emulator. Am I missing something obvious? The front-end code is simplified as compared to my actual use, but the functions code isn't simplified at all. And I can confirm that the firestore document is created and updated as I'd expect.

No error messages in the console or the logs.

#### Debug steps

- I've checked to make sure the functions code was correctly transpiled to JS. I bothed looked at the code output, as well as updated the onCreate code multiple times to ensure that function updated
- I hollowed out all my code inside the functions (as shown above), so I can confirm that the function itself isn't running
- The onUpdate function technically accepts two parameters. Same results with both parameters.
- I have not tried the functions in production, only with the emulator.

#### Related posts

[Why doesn't firestore onWrite trigger get invoked on firebase cloud functions emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127358/why-doesnt-firestore-onwrite-trigger-get-invoked-on-firebase-cloud-functions-em)

I'm not using any forbidden characters in the document selector, or at least I'm not getting that error message.

[Firebase Cloud Functions for Firestore are not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206137/firebase-cloud-functions-for-firestore-are-not-triggering)

Using functions 3.11.0, and the functions are async, hence they should implicitly return Promise. Results are the same when explicetely returning a value (e.g., `return 0`)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated

That's the official docs. As far as I can tell, I'm doing what the docs say. I could just be missing something blindingly obvious, though.

#### Other details

- macOS Big Sur 11.1 (20C69)
- Firebase CLI 9.1.0

The emulator should be up-to-date

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just forgot to import `onMusicUpdated` in the index.ts functions file. Hence the emulator never knew it existed!

Changed

```
// functions/src/index.ts

export { onMusicCreated } from './music'
```

to

```
// functions/src/index.ts

export { onMusicCreated, onMusicUpdated } from './music'
```